# error 500 - internal server error (Alta demanda aplicaciones en glassfish 4.1)

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, spring-mvc, glassfish

Tengo una aplicación web jsp (Sping MVC, Hibernate 4 y postgresql) corriendo en glassfish 4.1, esta aplicación funciona de forma correcta durante gran parte del día, pero en las tardes cuando tiene mayor demanda de los usuarios la pagina se cae solo mostrando el error "error 500 - internal server error" al actualizar la pagina vuelve a funcionar pero de manera intermitente a los segundos el error se vuelve a presentar hasta que reinicio el servidor. por lo que he investigado este error se genera por no proporcionar la configuración adecuada el servidor GlassFish por lo que les comparto mi configuración actual para que me puedan ayudar configurar mi servidor de aplicaciones y poder sanar este error.

Las caracteristicas de mi servidor virtual (VPS) es la siguiente, esto puede servir a la hora de proporcionar adecuadamente los recursos al JVM.

RAM:
CPU de 8GM : Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E7-4890 v2 @ 2.80GHz 2.80 GHz (4 procesadores)
SO: Windows 2012 r2 64bi
SSD: 160GB
Otros: La aplicación recibe al menos 1000 conexiones por minuto durante las tardes.

Esta es mi configuración de JVM option de glassfish

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar a mejorar la configuración de JVM option de GassFish 4.1 y poder obtener el mejor rendimiento de mi aplicación.

Trama del error, que se genera solamente cuando la aplicacion se cae que no es siempre es solo en horario punta de uso de la app y no todos los dias, el pool de conexiones es manejado por c3p0 en hibernate y permite abrir maximo 50 conexiones, la configuracion de postgresql esta configurada para tener 100 conexiones simultaneas, de todas formas cada vez que se ha presentado el error he revisado las conexiones existente y nunca he tenido mas de 54 conexiones simultaneas creadas en la DB pero la app no responde y me obliga a reiniciar el servidor windows server para poder poner en marcha la aplicación nuevamente.

```
  StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ls_erp.DAO.PrimaryKeySeq.getPrimaryKey(PrimaryKeySeq.java:539)
    at com.ls_erp.util.log.Escribir_Log(log.java:26)
    at com.ls_erp.Controllers.VentasController.PuntoVentas(VentasController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor247.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Conección a la base de datos por hibernate y c3p0

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Base de datos</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">SfddfdlkaL&%Sd52452</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">80</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: Sin saber que parte del código es el que da problemas será complicado darte una respuesta.

Comment: este es la trama del error que se genera en el server.log cada vez que se presenta el error, lo curioso es que este error se da solo cuando hay alta demanda, y las conecciones a base de datos son 50 que las que existen que son manejadas por c3p0 en el pool, postgresql me permite por configuracion un maximo de 100 conexiones pero no se alcanza ese limete.

Comment: Este método com.ls_erp.DAO.PrimaryKeySeq.getPrimaryKey() que hace? ¿Genera un número secuencial para las primary keys?  ¿Tiene algún tipo de bloqueo o control de concurrencia? Que hay en la línea 539 de PrimaryKeySeq.java?

Comment: Es un metodo que hace busca la secuencia de la tabla , en la linea 538 existe un catch, ```catch (HibernateException e) {
            tr.rollback();
            new log().Escribir_Log("getPrimaryKey", e.getMessage(), 10000, 0);//idempresa 0 significa inicio de session
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
             }
        }``` pero por lo que veo no guarda en la db el log, lo que me hace pensar que podria ser un error de la db, esta es postgresql y no se ha cambiado la configuracion para nada esta como por default.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a todos por el apoyo, después de tanto tiempo de investigación (meses) logre dar con el problema y solucionarlo, todo se trataba de la versión del jar de postgresql, mi aplicación usaba la versión postgresql-9.4.1209 la cual no es del todo compatible con la versión de postgresql 11.3 lo que causaba errores y caídas de la conexión con la base de datos, investigando encontré que la versión 100% compatible era la versión postgresql-42.2.9 lo que resolvió el problema y no volví a saber del error, muchas gracias a todos los que colaboraron y espero que le sirva a alguien esta respuesta.

existe una tabla con las compatibilidades de sus jar con cada version de postgresql en el siguiente link https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

El error 500 es muy genérico y generalmente a causa de otro error. Debes ver en el log de errores server.log si se están produciendo errores en la red y en especial las conexiones a Bases de Datos. Si la   base de datos debe estar configurada para soportar la cantidad de peticiones en hora punta, de lo contrario las peticiones desde el glassfish se perderán por timeout y en consecuencia puede dar un 500. Al menos esto último me ocurrió. Por ello es intermitente. Si no es la conexión  o pool de conexiones con la base de datos entonces revisa si hay algún otro recurso externo con el queninteractua la aplicación.  Lo primero es revisar los logs del día.